# Как слить несколько массивов в многомерный ассоциативный массив?

Tags: php

Необходимо преобразовать несколько массивов вида:

```
$a1 = array(279171, 438170);
$a2 = array(279171, 438156, 438157);
$a3 = array(279171, 438178);
$a4 = array(279172, 436113, 436115);
$a5 = array(279172, 436113, 438108);

$input = array($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5);
```

В структуру:

```
$result = array(
    '279171' => array(
        '438170',
        '438156' = array(
            '438157'
        ),
        '438178'
    ),
    '279172' => array(
        '436113' => array(
            436115,
            438108
        )
    )
);
```

Как создать функцию, которая берёт `$input` и возвращает `$result`?

Comment: Сформулируйте свой вопрос на русском языке.

Comment: @lalua, Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Имеется несколько массивов разной длины заполненные числами. Необходимо получить из них такой ассоциативный массив , чтобы первые элементы исходных массивов составляли первый уровень ассоциативного массива, вторые второй и так далее.

Comment: @lalua, большинство из нас прочитали и поняли что написано, но это не отменяет того, что на **ru**.so нужно писать на **русском** языке. Переведите.

Comment: у нового пользователя с репутацией 1 точно есть право редактировать вопрос?

Comment: @Sergiks редактировать собственный вопрос -- есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый входной массив – как ветка с листком на конце. Проходим его по одному элементу, создавая при необходимости подмассивы для всех элементов, кроме последнего. Последний вставляем как значение.

Проходя очередной узел смотрим, нет ли его уже как лепестка (значение, не ключ), и, если есть, переводим его в массив:

```
$a1 = array(279171, 438170);
$a2 = array(279171, 438156, 438157);
$a3 = array(279171, 438178);
$a4 = array(279172, 436113, 436115);
$a5 = array(279172, 436113, 438108);

$input = array($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5);

$result = array();    
foreach( $input as $item) {
    pushBranch( $item, $result);
}

function pushBranch( $arr, &$result) {
    $len = count( $arr);
    for($i=0, $cursor = &$result; $i<$len; $i++) {
        $el = $arr[ $i];
        if( $i === $len-1   // last
            &&  !array_key_exists( $el, $cursor)
            &&  false === array_search( $el, $cursor, true)) 
        {
            array_push( $cursor, $el);
        } else {                // middle
            if( array_key_exists( $el, $cursor)) {
                $cursor = &$cursor[ $el];
            } else {
                $key = array_search( $el, $cursor, true);
                if( false !== $key) unset( $cursor[ $key]);
                $cursor[ $el] = array();
                $cursor = &$cursor[ $el];
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r( $result);
```

### Результат:

```
Array (
    [279171] => Array (
            [0] => 438170
            [438156] => Array (
                    [0] => 438157
                )
            [438157] => 438178
        )
    [279172] => Array (
            [436113] => Array (
                    [0] => 436115
                    [1] => 438108
                )
        )
)
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/FArPVM)

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте ссылки.
На `JS` легко написал, а вот `PHP` чуть запутал, странно там... :)

### JS

```js
let a1 = [279171, 438170],
  a2 = [279171, 438156, 438157],
  a3 = [279171, 438178],
  a4 = [279172, 436113, 436115],
  a5 = [279172, 436113, 438108],
  input = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5];

function transf(inp) {
  let res = {}; // Будущее древо результата

  function push(item, ref) {
    // Создаём ссылку на древо, которую будем подменять
    let pointer = ref;
    
    // Проходим по внутренностям очередного массива
    item.forEach(i => {
      if (!(i in pointer)) // Если нет ключа, создаём его
        pointer[i] = {};

      pointer = pointer[i]; // Ставим ссылку на наш итерируемый указатель
    });
  }

  inp.forEach(e => {
    push(e, res); // Передаём очередной массив на добавление
  });

  return res;
}

console.info(transf(input));
```

### PHP

```
$a1 = array(279171, 438170);
$a2 = array(279171, 438156, 438157);
$a3 = array(279171, 438178);
$a4 = array(279172, 436113, 436115);
$a5 = array(279172, 436113, 438108);

$input = array($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5);

function transf($inp){
    $res = [];

    function push($item, &$ref){
        $pointer = &$ref;

        foreach($item as $i){
            if(!isset($pointer[$i]))
                $pointer[$i] = [];

            $pointer = &$pointer[$i];
        }

        return $ref;
    }

    foreach($inp as $e){
        push($e, $res);
    }

    return $res;
}

var_dump(transf($input));
```

[Исполнение примера онлайн-интерпретатором](https://repl.it/CcEI/0).

Comment: Как я заметил у автора 438170 это не массив, а просто string, у вас это массив с именем 438170. Но может автору это не принципиально.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, Вы очень проницательны. Можно поправить, если нужно, но главное принцип заполнения работает. Вроде бы.

Comment: Да, вроде работает. Я сам пытался это написать, но голову вскружило, трудно понять что автор хотел... Да и вообще идея автора напоминает нейкий костыль, наверно тама еще связь с mysql...

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, без контекста и сценария применения довольно сложно догадаться зачем это, может можно решить проще, чем преобразование массивов не самым очевидным способом.

Answer (score 0):

Костыль:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($input as $array) {
      $deep = count($array);
      if ($deep==2) $result["'".$array[0]."'"][] = (string)$array[1];
      if ($deep==3) $result["'".$array[0]."'"]["'".$array[1]."'"][] = (string)$array[2];
}
```

Comment: Очень плохой костыль, типа тех, что бесплатная мед. страховка инвалидам выдаёт. Если глубина будет... скажем 4? Рекурсия нужна.

Comment: То что нужна рекурсия - естественно, в случае если вложенность строго не ограничена. Но реализация требует несколько больше времени, чем я готов уделить данному вопросу. И как вижу по "множеству" ответов - тут я не одинок.

Comment: Остальным просто лень, наверное, жара разморила (моя причина :)).